# Custom Router for Maintenance

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like my ASP.NET Core MVC site to route all requests to a particular controller/action method whenever a particular file exists. The idea is that I can display a "site down for maintenance" page on an as-needed basis, just by creating a particular empty file.

After playing around with writing some custom middleware, it dawned on me that I should be able to create a custom `IRouter` which does this. Every route request should map to the "maintenance" route when that particular file exists. But I can't get it to work.

Here's the definition of the custom router:

```
public class OfflineRouteHandler : IRouter
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly IPAddress _remote;

    public OfflineRouteHandler( string offlinePath, string remoteIP )
    {
        _path = offlinePath;
        _remote = IPAddress.Parse( remoteIP );
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath( VirtualPathContext context )
    {
        // this returns a value...but RouteAsync is never called

        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

        if( context.AmbientValues.ContainsKey( "controller" ) )
            path.Append( context.AmbientValues["controller"] );

        if( context.AmbientValues.ContainsKey("action") )
        {
            if( path.Length > 0 ) path.Append( "/" );
            path.Append( context.AmbientValues["action"] );
        }

        return new VirtualPathData( this, "/" + path.ToString() );
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync( RouteContext context )
    {
        bool authorized = ( context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress == _remote );

        if( File.Exists(_path) && authorized )
        {
            // just for testing... but the method never gets called
            var i = 9;
            i++;
        }

        context.IsHandled = true;
    }
}
```

I invoke it in `Configure()` in Startup.cs as follows:

```
string offlinePath = Path.Combine( Directory.GetParent( env.WebRootPath ).FullName, "offline.txt" );

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.Routes.Add( new TemplateRoute( new OfflineRouteHandler( offlinePath, "50.3.3.2" ), "home/offline", new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver(routeOptions)) );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

`routeOptions` gets passed into the call to `Configure();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Avoid putting tags into the title an use the proper tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I went for the middleware approach.

It uses a similar approach to the `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` function, in that it modifies the `context.Request.Path` with the path. I've loaded the settings for the `OfflineMiddleware` using the [Options pattern](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects).

Essentially, when the file exists, the middleware modifies the path to the path you want "home/offline", and continues execution up the mvc pipeline.

As we've added `UseStaticFiles()` before the middleware, any static files on your offline page will be served - only requests that make it through to the MVC pipeline will be intercepted, and all of these requests will hit home/offline.

```cs
public class Startup
{
  //Partial Starup class
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.Configure<OfflineMiddlewareSettings>(settings =>
    { 
        settings.OfflinePath = "thePath";
        settings.RemoteIP = "50.3.3.2";
    });

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptionsMonitor<MyValues> monitor)
  {
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app. UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMiddleware<OfflineMiddleware>();
    app.UseMvc();
  }

}

public class OfflineMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly IPAddress _remote;

    public OfflineMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<OfflineMiddlewareSettings> settings)
    {
        _next = next;
        _path = settings.Value.OfflinePath;
        _remote = IPAddress.Parse(settings.Value.OfflinePath);
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        bool authorized = (context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress == _remote);

        if (File.Exists(_path) && authorized)
        {
            context.Request.Path = "home/offline";   
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public class OfflineMiddlewareSettings
{
    public string OfflinePath { get; set; }
    public string RemoteIP { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanx. And thanx, too, for the inline tip about storing configuration info in ConfigureServices. The way I'd been doing it heretofore is much more cumbersome than yours.